# Past day date in javascript never show correct results

Tags: javascript, date, dom

i need a date in "YYYY-mm-dd" format from some days past.
i write this function:

```
function getDifDate(d, numd) {
 d = stringToDate(d);
 d.setDate(d.getDate() - numd);
 return d;
}
```

then in another part of the program i write:

```
var tod = new Date();
switch(selPer.value) {
            case 1:         
                x= getDifDate(tod, 2);
                break;
            case 2:
                x= getDifDate(tod, 15);
                break;
            default:
                //default code block
        }
        console.log("Data1: "+ x);
```

but the x value, for example if i launch today my script return ever "25"

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, i don't need the difference between two date, i just want the date value resulting from todaydate-somenumberofdays

Comment: What does stringToDate function do?
You are passing a Date value into getDifDate and then it looks like you are trying to convert it from string to date with d = stringToDate(d); which you don't need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine even without DateJS

```
function getDifDate(d, numd) {
 d.setDate(d.getDate() - numd);
 return d;
}

var x;
var tod = new Date();
switch(1) {
            case 1:         
                x= getDifDate(tod, 2);
                break;
            case 2:
                x= getDifDate(tod, 15);
                break;
            default:
                //default code block
        }

console.log("Data1: ", x);
```

Check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gLwBIfAp7zFLEaV1KJ1O?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Use DateJS library

```
    Date.today().addDays(-1);
```

Documentation: https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

A working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vx1m67w1/1/

Comment: Return again "25", not 2014-08-25, just 25